# Unexpected behaviour of skimage.measure.LineModelND

Tags: python, scikit-image, data-fitting

I get a very unexpected result using skimage.measure LineModelND. It is not remotly close to a least square solution.

Here a code example showing the problem:

```
import skimage.measure
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create some data
x = np.arange(0,100,0.5)
y = 5 * x + 20
yNoise = y + np.random.uniform(low=-30.0, high=30, size=y.shape)
#Add some really bad data points
numOfBadData = 50
badDataIdx = np.random.choice(np.arange(y.shape[0]), numOfBadData)
yNoise[badDataIdx] = 0

data = np.vstack((x,yNoise)).T

#least square
p = np.polyfit(data[:,0], data[:,1], 1) #p = np.polyfit(x, yNoise, 1)
lineX=[np.min(x), np.max(x)]
yLeastSq = np.polyval(p, lineX)

#fit using LineModelND
model = skimage.measure.LineModelND()
model.estimate(data)
modelPredictY = model.predict_y(lineX)

plt.figure('Data compare')
plt.clf()
plt.plot(x, yNoise, '.g', label='data points')
plt.plot(lineX, yLeastSq, color='red', label='least square solution')
plt.plot(lineX, modelPredictY, '-', color='blue', label='LineModelND')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Giving:
[OutputImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKH4A.png)

I understand that the polynomial fit is taking the distance parallel to the y-axis, which is not the same as using the perpendicular distance as in lineModelND. Never the less I expected something close in this example.

Any idea why those two methods are giving very different results?

Comment: I've replicated the behavior you see.  I think what's happening here is that LineModelND imposes the additional constraint that the fitted line should run through the center of the data.  We'll address this problem: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2891

Comment: Thank you for finding the root cause for the problem. Will it be possible to use linalg.lstsq to solve the problem? This approach will have a problem with vertical lines again. But it may be worth thinking about it.

Comment: We dug into the issue a bit further, and I think the difference between the two methods is that the one optimizes for the differences in y-values, whereas the other minimizes projection distances.  Either can be considered a valid approach, but will yield different results.

Comment: There is now a PR to improve the documentation: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/2903

Comment: @stefan van der Walt: Using the fit.py from [https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/2903/files](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/2903/files) and a very simple dataset replacing lines 5 to 12 in the example above still lead to unexpected results:  `x = np.array([0,1,3]);
y = np.array([3,2,3]);
yNoise = y` Am I doing something stupid here. Since the slope is close to Zero in this example the results should be close.

Comment: For this data, the two models are indistinguishable for me.  What do you observe?

Comment: Strange. I got: [https://imgur.com/a/rMDCD](https://imgur.com/a/rMDCD)

Comment: Can you try again, and if you still see the bad result post that to a Gist?

Comment: I double checked to use the new fit.py by restarting everything and clearing the cache. The code I use is here: [https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a4a53352a57888b125f48b6be4091587](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a4a53352a57888b125f48b6be4091587) But still getting this strange result. What are you getting?

Comment: Your code evaluates the model at the wrong positions: `modelPredictY = model.predict_y([0,99])`

Comment: Stupit typo of mine. I consider the issue solved, thanks.